# Remote keyboard emulator over mobile web page?

Tags: keyboard, emulation, mouse, web

Is there (preferably open source) solution to emulate keyboard and mouse using web page - preferably working on the smartphone. The main goal is not to have to install anything on smartphone.

I would imagine it would work as follows:

- server - installed on the pi - webserver translating data send from client to mouse movement and keyboard inputs on the pi,
- client - any smartphone using web browser, connected to said server - I would image part of the page would emulate touchpad and other part would be on screen keyboard.

I did some quite extensive search but could not find anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

How about [simple keyboard](https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/demos/)? (project page on [Github](https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard))

[image]

Your webpage could submit either single characters, or complete text lines (e.g. SSH commands) to the webserver, and the webserver would then run them via `shell_exec` or similar, or feed individual characters to a pipe created with `proc_open`.

Make sure this webpage is not accessible to everyone without authentication, unless you want your Pi to become part of a botnet in the next couple of days.

There's also a [request](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/189) to provide Android support for `barrier`, which would do exactly what you describe, but AFAIK it's not ready yet.